# Buffer generator

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, generator

I have a consumer which takes data from my generator. Now the consumer and the generator take about the same time to process, so my total run time is:

`(t_generator + t_consumer) * number_of_items`

I now want to run the generator for the next item while my consumer process the current item, so my consumer does not have to wait `t_generator`

How is this usually implemented in Python3?

EDIT (added small sample):

```
g = my_generator() # cannot change this

intermediate = ??? # Do whatever you want. Maybe something like a queue which takes n from g and yields to consumer whenever ready?

processed p = consume(intermediate) # cannot change this
```

Comment: Is the generator/consumer work IO bound or CPU bound?

Comment: Generator is CPU bound and consumer GPU bound

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

You aren't providing any sample code so all I can do is point you to the documentation. If you have trouble check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm) tutorial by tutorialspoint on multi threading in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can you threading (since your producer & consumer are not using the same resources):

```
from threading import Queue, Thread
g = my_generator() # cannot change this

q = Queue()
def fill_up():
    for stuff in g:
        q.put(stuff)


Thread(target=fill_up).start()

consume((q.get() for _ in range(2**32))
```